# How do I train a CNN to learn bounding boxes from labeled images?

Tags: tensorflow, face-detection, conv-neural-network, bounding-box

I am trying to detect faces of specific people in images. Two people. I have 2k images of each of the two people that are labelled. These are normal snapshots, so there are other people in the images. In some cases, both people appear in the same image.

I used Adobe Lightroom's face detection to label the images. In retrospect, this was a mistake; it's very limited. For example, after labelling enough images, LR guesses at the labels that should be applied. These guesses are rather good. However, you must confirm each guess before it can be used to select photos.

Since I already have a substantial corpus of labeled images, I hoped there was a way I could learn the bounding boxes from the labeled images, rather than use something like `labelImg` to manually redo work I have already performed.

Ideally, I'm looking for a TensorFlow model that I can load and run on the labelled images where the output is the bounding box. If this is a fool's errand, I would also like to know that.

Comment: So you are performing face detection on a picture with multiple faces, then face recognition to identify only the 2 people?

Comment: Some of the photos have multiple people, some have none. It's ten years' worth of mobile phone photos from two phones. There are 40k photos. I'm trying to pick out photos of a couple for a gift.